# Using the JPA Criteria API, can you do a fetch join that results in only one join?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, criteria-api

Using JPA 2.0. It seems that by default (no explicit fetch), `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` fields are fetched in 1 + N queries, where N is the number of results containing an Entity that defines the relationship to a distinct related entity. Using the Criteria API, I might try to avoid that as follows:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> query = builder.createQuery(MyEntity.class);
Root<MyEntity> root = query.from(MyEntity.class);
Join<MyEntity, RelatedEntity> join = root.join("relatedEntity");
root.fetch("relatedEntity");
query.select(root).where(builder.equals(join.get("id"), 3));
```

The above should ideally be equivalent to the following:

```
SELECT m FROM MyEntity m JOIN FETCH myEntity.relatedEntity r WHERE r.id = 3
```

However, the criteria query results in the root table needlessly being joined to the related entity table twice; once for the fetch, and once for the where predicate. The resulting SQL looks something like this:

```
SELECT myentity.id, myentity.attribute, relatedentity2.id, relatedentity2.attribute 
FROM my_entity myentity 
INNER JOIN related_entity relatedentity1 ON myentity.related_id = relatedentity1.id 
INNER JOIN related_entity relatedentity2 ON myentity.related_id = relatedentity2.id 
WHERE relatedentity1.id = 3
```

Alas, if I only do the fetch, then I don't have an expression to use in the where clause.

Am I missing something, or is this a limitation of the Criteria API? If it's the latter, is this being remedied in JPA 2.1 or are there any vendor-specific enhancements?

Otherwise, it seems better to just give up compile-time type checking (I realize my example doesn't use the metamodel) and use dynamic JPQL TypedQueries.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Instead of `root.join(...)` you can use `root.fetch(...)` which returns `Fetch<>` object.

<del>`Fetch<>` is descendant of `Join<>`</del> but it can be used in similar manner.

You just need to cast `Fetch<>` to `Join<>` it should work for EclipseLink and Hibernate

```
...
Join<MyEntity, RelatedEntity> join = (Join<MyEntity, RelatedEntity>)root.fetch("relatedEntity");
...
```

Comment: Fetch is neither a subinterface of Join nor Expression, so I can't assign it to a Join and I can't use it in a where clause (for example). Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Fetch.html So, how is this possible? Is it provider-specific?

Comment: Sorry, you should cast it. It should work at least for Hybernate as described here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-from-fetch I've fixed my answer.

Comment: This worked for me, but casting to a `Join<MyEntity, RelatedEntity>` caused my IDE to flag the statement as a warning.
I found that casting to `org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.SingularAttributeJoin<MyEntity, RelatedEntity>` made the warning go away.

Calling `root.fetch` does the following:
    `FetchParent#fetch(String)`
    `AbstractFromImpl#fetch(String) [Implementation of FetchParent]`
    `AbstractFromImpl#fetch(SingularAttribute, JoinType)`
    `AbstractFromImpl#constructJoin(SingularAttribute,JoinType) [Returns SingularAttributeJoin]`

Comment: It works, thanks, but the more I use JPA Criteria the more I find it verbose & not intuitive.

Comment: Kind of old topic, but maybe you will know: even tho it's possible to cast from `Fetch` to `Join` you can't do `fetch.on(...)`, because it will say that `with clause cannot be used with fetch join - use filters`. I need to add an extra condition to join (besides ID). When I just do `root.join(...)` and then `join.on(...)` correct joins are generated, but they are not fetching that joined data (no fields listed in selects). Maybe you know some workaround?

Comment: This really works. But, is it a best solution? It's seems to me that it's just some kind of workaround? `Join` interface is not a subtype of `Fetch`. Their common interface is `FetchParent`. It has narrower scope of methods. I really don't get where's that hidden implementation located? But for this example `join.get()` works.

Comment: @ChrisParton Typecast to `(Join)` to make your IDE happy!

Comment: Excellent, strange not to have something more documented about this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11):

Starting with JPA 2.1 you can use dynamic entity graphs for this.  Remove your fetch and specify an entity graph as follows:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> query = builder.createQuery(MyEntity.class);
Root<MyEntity> root = query.from(MyEntity.class);
Join<MyEntity, RelatedEntity> join = root.join("relatedEntity");
query.select(root).where(builder.equal(join.get("id"), 3));
EntityGraph<MyEntity> fetchGraph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(MyEntity.class);
fetchGraph.addSubgraph("relatedEntity");
entityManager.createQuery(query).setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", fetchGraph);
```

Comment: The correct method from CriteriaBuilder is equal not equals

Answer (score 1):

Using `root.fetch()` on EclipseLink will create a SQL with `INNER JOIN` because have 3 types and the default is INNER.

```
INNER,  LEFT,  RIGHT;
```

The suggestion is to use CreateQuery.

```
TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
```

EDIT: You can Cast the root to From like this:

```
From<?, ?> join = (From<?, ?>) root.fetch("relatedEntity");
```

Comment: The question is about CriteriaQuery it does not have setHint

Comment: I explained how to help using another method to solve.  If you won´t understand I can´t do nothing.

Comment: When you are using the criteria API to build a query you won't throw away your entire code to instead build a query with TypedQuery so you can set a hint See "Using the JPA Criteria API" from the title of the question. You might as well suggest how to do it with sql only

Comment: I can do entityManager.createQuery(CriteriaQuery) like this! You can use: String, CriteriaQuery, CriteriaUpdate and CriteriaDelete.

Comment: Read this API https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html

Do you see a setHint?

Comment: Read this. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/gjitv/index.html. Here you have a Query, that you use setHint. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html

Comment: This question is not about the Query interface. It is about CriteriaQuery that does not implement that interface. You might as well suggest him some SQL. Please read the question and my comments again

Comment: Man, that is a SUGGESTION. I will remove it ok?

Comment: @FábioAlmeida 1000 points! Thanks a lot! Solved my problem after a day of work!

Comment: Casting to From <?, ?> works beautifully to add constraints on the joined entity, that saved me a ton of time, thanks.