# JPA CriteriaQuery with ListJoin

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, join

I'm working with JPA CriteriaBuilder, CriteriaQuery etc. and static metamodels for typesafe queries, like here for example: [click.](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/)

I have 3 tables: Client, Package, Vegetable.

Every client has 1 or more packages, and those packages contain multiple vegetables.

What I have now:

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Client> query = builder.createQuery(Client.class);
Root<Client> root = query.from(Client.class);
ListJoin<Package, Vegetable> join = root.join(Client_.packages).join(Package_.vegetables);
TypedQuery<Client> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
return typedQuery.getResultList();
```

The `ListJoin` I added recently. Point is what Hibernate does: generates the whole select for all fields in `Client` class from the `Client` table inner joined with `Package` and `Vegetable`, but it doesn't actually selects those fields from joined tables. It gets every package by ID and then every vegetable by ID, thus doing `n+1` selects.

Without the `ListJoin` it doesn't inner join those tables, but I'm working on it right now so I added those joins. Now I want to select all the fields from those classes so I get whole object hierarchy with 1 select. I tried doing something with projections like in the link I gave in `Projecting the result` chaper, but I have no idea how to connect that with `ListJoin`.

Is that even possible in this situation? When I run this query on database (with manually added all the fields from joined tables) it works fine, but would Hibernate handle that? And if so - how to project the result so it selects all the fields from 3 tables joined together and constructs whole object hierarchy, all with 1 select?

//Edit: managed to retrieve all packages with a single query, but going further raises exception:

```java
Root<Client> root = query.from(Root.class);

ListJoin<Client, Package> join = root.join(Client_.packages);
ListJoin<Package, Vegetable> secondJoin = join.join(Package_.vegetables);

root.fetch(Client_.packages);
```

Naturally, I tried to add: `join.fetch(Package_.vegetables);` but it raises the `org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list`, no idea what is that.

As to the latest comment: gonna try that now.

//Edit2: I added 2 fetches (couldn't cast them to `Join` like in that answer, compiler errors):

```java
Fetch<Client, Package> join = root.fetch(Client_.packages);
Fetch<Package, Vegetable> secondJoin = join.fetch(Package_.vegetables);
```

It raises `org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags`, known error I guess so at least got something to search for.

//Edit3: Changed it both to Sets and it works, thanks, couldn't have done it without the `Fetch instead of Join` suggestion, seems kinda unintuitive to me.

Comment: You need to use root.fetch(...) instead of root.join(...), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306655/using-the-jpa-criteria-api-can-you-do-a-fetch-join-that-results-in-only-one-joi.

Comment: Couold you please write out the final solution you used? I've been looking for this solution FOREVER. I'd rephrase the title to get more hits for people who need to to something like, "JPA CriteriaQuery Deep And Nested Joins For OnetoMany Relationships".