# What is the difference between FetchMode and JoinType in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a criteria query to retrieve parent and all its children. But hibernate is firing multiple queries to fetch children. I have used default InnerJoin fetch while creating criteria, and also tried setting fetchMode.Join. But nothing works.

So, what is the difference between FetchMode.Join and JoinType. I thought Jointype alone is sufficient to fetch data from both the tables in a single query. But is this the case?

Secondly, when criteria query will fire multiple queries to fetch childrens.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` says that related entities will be retrieved using join SQL query, but it also breaks laziness, it means even if you mark your child entity as `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` it won't work. In order to prevent the secondary query use `join fetch` - [Using the JPA Criteria API, can you do a fetch join that results in only one join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306655/using-the-jpa-criteria-api-can-you-do-a-fetch-join-that-results-in-only-one-joi)
and I don't recommend to use `@Fetch` at all.

Follow up to read: `Java Persistence with Hibernate. 2nd edition` - `15.4.5 Dynamic fetching with joins`:

> Queries ignore any fetching strategy you’ve defined in mapping
>   metadata with @org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch. For example, mapping
>   the bids collection with org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode.JOIN has
>   no effect on the queries you write. The dynamic fetching strategy of
>   your query ignores the global fetching strategy. On the other hand,
>   Hibernate doesn’t ignore the mapped fetch plan: Hibernate always
>   considers a FetchType.EAGER, and you may see several additional SQL
>   statements when you execute your query.

Just so you know - `EAGER` does not work for queries - https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/
It almost always generates additional queries, so, that's the answer for you question - `when criteria query will fire multiple queries to fetch childrens?`